# "Command not found" after pipe

Tags: macos, shell, path, pipe, homebrew

Some commands return "Command not found" if they are called after a pipe.

I checked if/where they are installed, and in recent versions, and if they are in the $PATH.
Background: MacOS 10.14.5, gnu utilities and other commands installed via homebrew, manually set $PATHS and $MANPATHS.

```
$ echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n} | cut -d '/' -f 1
-bash:  cut: Command not found.
$ echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n} | grep '/usr/'
-bash:  grep: Command not found.

$ which cut
/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/cut
$ which grep
/usr/local/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin/grep

$ cut --version
cut (GNU coreutils) 8.31... 
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 3.3...

$ bash --version
GNU bash, Version 5.0.7(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0)...

$ echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin
/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin
/usr/local/opt/ed/libexec/gnubin
/usr/local/opt/findutils/libexec/gnubin
/usr/local/opt/gawk/libexec/gnubin
/usr/local/opt/gnu-indent/libexec/gnubin
/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin
/usr/local/opt/gnu-tar/libexec/gnubin
/usr/local/opt/gnu-time/libexec/gnubin
/usr/local/opt/gnu-units/libexec/gnubin
/usr/local/opt/gnu-which/libexec/gnubin
/usr/local/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin
/usr/local/opt/inetutils/libexec/gnubin
/usr/local/opt/make/libexec/gnubin
/Users/xxxx/.jenv/shims
/Users/xxxx/.jenv/bin
/usr/local/opt/icu4c/sbin
/usr/local/opt/icu4c/bin
/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin
/usr/local/opt/binutils/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/opt/X11/bin
/usr/local/opt/e2fsprogs/bin
/usr/local/opt/e2fsprogs/sbin
```

The commands do work in single lines and other multiline inputs:

```
$ echo "asdfdfasdfsadf" | cut -c 4-8
fdfas
$ echo "asdfdfasdfsadf" | grep 'df'
asdfdfasdfsadf
$ echo "asdfdfasdfsadf" | grep -v 'df'
$ ls -l | grep aps
drwx------   25 xxxx staff  800 Mai 17 23:33 Maps
```

I also tried `sort` and `xargs` after a pipe: same behaviour.

Maybe the multiline return of `echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}` is the culprit, or the installation/setup is faulty?

The latter is more likely, because of this:

```
$ which cut
/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/cut
$ whereis cut
/usr/bin/cut
$ which grep
/usr/local/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin/grep
$ whereis grep
/usr/bin/grep
```

I admit being thoroughly confused.

Comment: Hm. Try `echo -e "${PATH//:/\\n}" | grep usr`? Or `echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}  |grep usr`? Or `echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}|grep usr`?  If you look closely here: `-bash:  grep: Command not found.` there are two spaces after `bash:`, which looks like bash is eating a space from somewhere and interpreting the command as `' grep'`. Maybe you typed some unreadable character there, try it again in another window and rewrite it (not copy) to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

@Kamil Cuk
All your suggestions worked, via copy-paste. And you were right about the unreadable character.

I opened the **bash history** in BBEdit and looked for unusual characters, and **found `\x{A0}` (non-breaking space) between `|` and the following commands.**

*...And because I always had reused the line via up-arrow key, that gremlin had persisted in all tries.*

Thank you for your fast help! Can you make the comment an answer?